Joint distribution of dependent variables
Say I have two (dependent) Gaussian random variables $X\sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y)$ representing physical values that are related via a function $X=f(Y;z_i)$ depending also on a number of other values $z_i$. Suppose now that I have taken measurements for each of the $z_i$, so that I have a definite function relating possible values for $X$ and $Y$ under the "current state of the system". How do I obtain the "most likely" combination of values for $X$ and $Y$? Is this kind if problem even well-defined, or must I be more strict with what I allow $f$ to be?
I feel like I have to somehow combine the two independent distributions via $f$ into some kind of "better-informed" distribution for $Y$, which I can then find the expected value of. I'm imagining a kind of pull back of the $X$-distribution along $f$, e.g. $P_Y(y)=P_X(f(y))$, which I then form a weighted sum with the original $Y$-distibution using some scalar coefficients (they seem unavoidable, and I guess they must measure how much you care about adhering to each distribution). Although at this point I am somewhat lost - is this the correct procedure?
Edit: To avoid confusion I’ll give an example. Say I’ve empirically determined that $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$, and I then take a new measurement of the system that reveals that, in its current state, it must  be true that $X+Y=1$. What estimates should I make for the values of $X$ and $Y$ here? By symmetry it seems that I should estimate $0.5$ for each, but I’m looking for a more general method.
Edit II: I’ve realised the problem can’t be solved without knowing the joint distribution $p(X,Y)$, and once knowing this distribution, the restriction to $\{x=f(y)\}$ determines the ”constrained” distribution over which to calculate expected value.

The question isn't clear to me. Do you need some subscript for $X$ and/or $Y$? Maybe a concrete example would help. Is this just scatter plot smoothing on $(X_i, Y_i)$ pairs?

@ZackFisher sorry for confusion - only one variable $X$ and one variable $Y$. I’ll make an edit clarifying with an example.
